# REST API Laravel: How to return a complex JSON response from an API

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel-5

I'm a beginner with Laravel and PHP generally and was asked to create an API to get an array of data with an output like this:

```
"stages": [
    {
        "id": "1f149fc7-5270-11e5-b3f3-3417ebe4606c",
        "User": 
            {
                "userId": "262b990f-526f-11e5-b3f3-3417ebe4606c",
                "firstName": "Name",
                "LastName": "last Name"
                "country": 
                        {
                            "countryId": 1,
                            "countryName": "country"
                        },
                "city": "city",
                "profilePicPath": "/path/abf115b7_5258_11e5_b3f3_3417ebe4606c/photo.jpeg"
            },

        "uploadDate": "2015-09-03 02:15:21",
        "stageTypeId": "1f149fc7-5270-11e5-b3f3-3417ebe4606c",
        "stageFilePath": "/path/MjYyYjk5MGYtNTI2Zi0xMWU1LWIzZjMtMzQxN2ViZTQ2MDZj.mp4",
        "stageFilePhypath": "/path/MjYyYjk5MGYtNTI2Zi0xMWU1LWIzZjMtMzQxN2ViZTQ2MDZj.mp4",
        "commentsCount":
            {
                "count": 100,
            },
        "like":
            {
                "count": 100
            },
```

It is like twitter/instagram API where data returned is complete and complex. I have created an API with simple responses but not something like this where I have to get data from all other tables for each array of data that will be returned by the service. Also this would be easy if the data that I'm getting is not an array but for a specific ID. Is there a way can implement getting all data for each result array? Do I need to create one complex query to gather every information that I need?

Please help. Any advice, hints, tutorials will be really appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a JSON syntax, so search for JSON tutorials and you will find serializers that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**consider** if the **name of model is User** than to return the values we simply do this

**return Response::JSON(User::all());**

And If it shows Class Response not found then just add these files in the controller file in which U r using it

**Use Response;**